# Django: How to show a PointField in a map from a html template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, openstreetmap

I have a Django class in my models.py, similar to the following:

```
class MyClass(Model):
    ....
    description = TextField()
    location = PointField()
```

In my views.py:

```
template = loader.get_template('my_class.html')
context = {
    'my_class': MyClass.objects.filter(....),
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Finally, from my my_class.html template I can easily print each of the properties in my MyClass object:

```
{{ my_class.description }}
```

But {{ my_class.location}} just prints something like POINT (-13.716858926262476 50.42083468131796).

Is there an easy way to show the point in an OpenStreetMap map? (Similar to the map in the admin page when using OSMGeoAdmin)

Do I need to create a form for that if this template is read-only? (I dont need to edit any of the fields)

(I'm using Django 3.2 in case that is important)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to either use iframe with Google Map API key [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/map-generator) or JavaScript (may be something like [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/).